# Взаимодействие с сгенерированным GridView

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net, asp.net-webforms

Некоторым образом генерируется GridView1:

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" DataKeyNames="Id" AllowPaging="True" AllowSorting="True" OnSorting="GridView1_Sorting" class="table table-hover" >
    <Columns>
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="picture" SortExpression="picture">
            <ItemTemplate>  
                <asp:Image ID="Image1" runat="server" Height="90px" Width="60px" ImageUrl='<%#"data:Image/png;base64," + Convert.ToBase64String((byte[])Eval("picture")) %>' />
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="name" SortExpression="name">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("name") %>'></asp:Label>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="autor" SortExpression="autor">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:Label ID="Label2" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("autor") %>'></asp:Label>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="editor" SortExpression="editor">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:Label ID="Label3" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("editor") %>'></asp:Label>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="year" SortExpression="year"> 
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:Label ID="Label4" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("year") %>'></asp:Label>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="type" SortExpression="type">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:Label ID="Label6" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("type") %>'></asp:Label>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
    </Columns>
    <EditRowStyle HorizontalAlign="Justify" VerticalAlign="Middle" />
    <EmptyDataTemplate>
        No result for search!
    </EmptyDataTemplate>
</asp:GridView>
```

Каким образом мне получить значения этого GridView1 для дальнейшей обработки в функции? (Сортировка, фильтрация, перелистывание и другое).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Короткий вариант - никак. Механизм датабайндинга в ASP.NET Web Forms для этого не приспособлен.

Как работает датабайндинг:

Вы выставляете у грида `DataSource` и вызываете `DataBind()`. Он пробегается по данным, достает из них то, что должно быть *отображено*, преобразует в свойства конкретных контролов - `Label.Text` и сохраяет их во ViewState. За счет этого данные в гриде не сбрасываются при постбеках - нажатиях на кнопки на странице - грид просто рендерит сохраненные значения контролов.

Т.е. сохраняется только то, что видно в выходном html - лабелы в в таблице на первой странице грида.

DataSource во вьюстейт не сохраняется. Совсем. Если вы хотите отсортировать, отфильтровать, перелистать, сделать что-то еще - вам нужно *заново* выбрать данные, отфильтровать или отсортировать их, опять положить в `Grid.DataSource` и вызвать `Grid.DataBind()`

Comment: Мне помогло, спасибо. Отличный ответ, как и всегда:)